# Uploading documents to document library in SharePoint 2010 with OData Rest API

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I cannot seem to find much information on the SharePoint 2010 OData Rest API. Does anyone know if it is possible to upload documents using the REST API for SharePoint 2010? I can query document libraries, and even add items and modify items. But how do I attach a document to one of these document library item? Is this even possbile?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this will help: [Upload file to SharePoint 2010 using PowerShell and the OData API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195361/upload-file-to-sharepoint-2010-using-powershell-and-the-odata-api)