# Upload file to SharePoint 2010 using PowerShell and the OData API

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, odata, powershell-3.0

I'm attempting to upload a file to SharePoint 2010:

```
Function Add-Attachments()
{

    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [int]$Id,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string[]]$Paths
    )

    BEGIN {}
    PROCESS {

        $url = "http://server/resource/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/TheList($Id)/Attachments"

        Foreach ($Path in $Paths) {

            Write-Verbose "Attaching $Path ..."
            $headers = @{
                'Slug' = "TheList|$Id|$(Split-Path $path -Leaf)"
            }

            $Payload = @{filename=(Split-Path $path -Leaf);filecontent=([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($path))}

            Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Post -UseDefaultCredentials -Body $Payload -Headers $headers

        } # Foreach

    } # PROCESS
    END {}

}

Add-Attachments -Id 1234 -Paths 'C:\Users\gandalf\Desktop\test.txt' -verbose
```

I get an error that reads:

> Invoke-WebRequest :  
>      An error occurred while
>   processing this request.  At
>   C:\Users\gandalf\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts\SP\SharePoint2010.ps1:382
>   char:13
>   +             Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Post -UseDefaultCredentials -Bod ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest],
>   WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

** edit **

The file's original content:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam
>   lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam
>   viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor.
>   Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam
>   tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut
>   libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
>   amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis
>   felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor
>   nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit
>   pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in urna
>   ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros. Donec viverra mi quis quam
>   pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et
>   magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum
>   accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis semper ac in
>   est.

The script does create a file on the server, but with this content:

> filename=test.txt&filecontent=Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%2c+consectetur+adipiscing+elit.+Donec+a+diam+lectus.+Sed+sit+amet+ipsum+mauris.+Maecenas+congue+ligula+ac+quam+viverra+nec+consectetur+ante+hendrerit.+Donec+et+mollis+dolor.+Praesent+et+diam+eget+libero+egestas+mattis+sit+amet+vitae+augue.+Nam+tincidunt+congue+enim%2c+ut+porta+lorem+lacinia+consectetur.+Donec+ut+libero+sed+arcu+vehicula+ultricies+a+non+tortor.+Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%2c+consectetur+adipiscing+elit.+Aenean+ut+gravida+lorem.+Ut+turpis+felis%2c+pulvinar+a+semper+sed%2c+adipiscing+id+dolor.+Pellentesque+auctor+nisi+id+magna+consequat+sagittis.+Curabitur+dapibus+enim+sit+amet+elit+pharetra+tincidunt+feugiat+nisl+imperdiet.+Ut+convallis+libero+in+urna+ultrices+accumsan.+Donec+sed+odio+eros.+Donec+viverra+mi+quis+quam+pulvinar+at+malesuada+arcu+rhoncus.+Cum+sociis+natoque+penatibus+et+magnis+dis+parturient+montes%2c+nascetur+ridiculus+mus.+In+rutrum+accumsan+ultricies.+Mauris+vitae+nisi+at+sem+facilisis+semper+ac+in+est.

What am I missing?  Do I need to include the content length?  Set the MIME type?

Comment: Have you tried with Fiddler to see traffic from server ? If on premise check ULS log

Comment: A few questions: 1) Are you trying to attach a file to an existing list item or are you wanting to just upload the file to a folder? /Attachments should be specific to attaching to list items. 2) Is this being uploaded from a server in the farm or is this remote? 3) What line in the code does 382 point to? (as you only have 35 lines, I assume there's more).

Comment: 1. attach file to existing list item 2. uploaded from workstation 3. needs research

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create an attachment resource the following properties have to be specified:

```
Endpoint Uri: http://server/site/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/entityset(itemid)/Attachments
Method: POST
Headers:
   Slug: "entityset|itemid|name"
   ContentType: */* 
Body: content
```

Having said that, my conslution that the specified `body` parameter (`$payload`) is invalid in the provided example.

The following example demonstrates how to upload attachment file via SharePoint 2010 REST Interface:

```
Function Add-Attachments()
{

    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$WebUrl, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$ListName, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [int]$ItemId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$SourcePath
    )

    BEGIN {}
    PROCESS {
        $endpointUri = New-Object System.Uri("$WebUrl/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/$ListName($ItemId)/Attachments")
        $fileName = (Split-Path $SourcePath -Leaf)
        $fileContent = ([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($SourcePath))
        $headers = @{
                 'Slug' = "$ListName|$ItemId|$fileName";
        }

        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $endpointUri -Method Post -UseDefaultCredentials -Body $fileContent -Headers $headers -ContentType "*/*"

    } # PROCESS
    END {}

}
```

Usage:

```
Add-Attachments -WebUrl "http://contoso.intranet.com/" -ListName "Tasks" -ItemId 1 -SourcePath "C:\Users\user\Documents\SharePointUserGuide.docx" -verbose
```

**Update**

After performing some analysis via Fiddler, it was determined that the proper endpoint url should be:

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Attachments HTTP/1.1
```

instead of:

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Tasks(<id>)/Attachments HTTP/1.1
```

**Modified example**

```
Function Add-Attachments()
{

    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$WebUrl, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$ListName, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [int]$ItemId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$SourcePath
    )

    BEGIN {}
    PROCESS {
        $endpointUri = New-Object System.Uri("$WebUrl/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Attachments")  
        $fileName = (Split-Path $SourcePath -Leaf)
        $fileContent = ([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($SourcePath))
        $headers = @{
                 'Slug' = "$ListName|$ItemId|$fileName";
        }

        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $endpointUri -Method Post -UseDefaultCredentials -Body $fileContent -Headers $headers -ContentType "*/*"

    } # PROCESS
    END {}

}
```

Comment: Would this work to *replace* a file (assuming same names) with a new version?  Or would the method need to be `PUT`?

Comment: The function returns `System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.`.  On a positive note, the file is attached to the task and its content appears to be valid.  Thoughts?

Comment: [Relevant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696981/get-http-request-and-tolerate-500-server-error-in-powershell)

Comment: It seems so, tried to consume the same request via c# Web Request but never encountered the same error..

Comment: Or [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43543/how-to-debug-500-internal-server-error-when-calling-web-services)?

Comment: Looks like the issue was related with endpoint url, just updated the answer

Comment: how to use this with javascript please help me